# Programmatically uploading a file?

Tags: java, box-api

I'm developing a small program that uploads and downloads files from my box account.

I looked at the docs about uploading files and I found this code:

```
BoxFolder rootFolder = BoxFolder.getRootFolder(api);
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("My File.txt");
rootFolder.uploadFile(stream, "My File.txt");
stream.close();
```

I don't really understand how it works. Where can I put the path to the file I want to upload? Or should I use different code?

Answer (score 0):

[The constructor for `FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream-java.lang.String-) takes in a path to a file. The example in the documentation is uploading a file with the path "./My File.txt" relative to the current directory.

To make it a bit clearer, here's an example using a full path:

```
BoxFolder rootFolder = BoxFolder.getRootFolder(api);
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream("/path/to/My File.txt");
rootFolder.uploadFile(stream, "My File.txt");
stream.close();
```